# removing and adding css class onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am having some trouble configuring how to change css classes of a span within a div on onclick event.

javascript:

```
$(document).on('click', '.list_accordion_toggle', function (event) {
            $(this).toggleClass('list_item collapse').next().toggle();
        });
```

view:

```
<div class="list_accordion_toggle" id="letter">
        <span data-bind=" text: Letter"></span>
        <span class="icon-minus-sign"></span>
    </div>
```

when the user clicks on the div the icon-minus-sign should be replaced with icon-plus-sign and will continue to toggle with every click.

do i use the toggleClass or removeClass then addClass?

Comment: use remove class and add class becuse toogle remove and add class 

but dont set  icon-minus-sign  with  icon-plus-sign  and vice versa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).on('click', '.list_accordion_toggle', function (event) {
    $(this).toggleClass('list_item collapse').next().toggle();
    $(this).find('.icon-minus-sign, .icon-plus-sign').toggleClass('icon-minus-sign icon-plus-sign')
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/m88J6/)

Comment: This has also added extra divs to all my nested elements which i don't need

Comment: Although this works great, wouldn't it be better to do this through CSS instead of JS ? I mean, as soon as the parent class changes, it's quite easy to set different CSS styles for a child.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    iCount=0;
    $(document).on('click', '.list_accordion_toggle', function (event) {
        if(iCount==0){
        $(this).addClass(icon-minus-sign);
        $(this).removeClass(icon-plus-sign);
        iCount=1;
    }
    else{
        $(this).addClass(icon-plus-sign);
        $(this).removeClass(icon-minus-sign);
        }
    });
```